# Adding non printable chars to a string in Java?

Tags: java, string, ascii

I need to add some non printable chars to a string in java so it can be sent down a tcp pipe. the chars mean something to the protocol I am using (record separator and end of message respectively)

what is the best way to go about doing this?

Ideally I'l like to refer to them as constants so that I can use string concatonation/stringbuilder/string.format to add them where required, without having to type them out.

For the curious the chars I need are ASCIIx1E (Record separator) and ACSIIx03 (End of Text).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
public final class ProtocolConstants {
    public final char RECORD_SEPARATOR = 0x1e;
    public final char END_OF_TEXT = 0x03;

    private ProtocolConstants() {}
}
```

something like that?

Answer (score 6):

If you wish, you can write these as Unicode literals (in chars or Strings):

```
final String endOfText = "\u0003";
```

- [Unicode charts](http://unicode.org/charts/)
- [Java Language Specification Lexical Structure chapter](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html)

I am assuming that you don't literally want [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) for a byte-based protocol (the chars are still 16 bits).

Answer (score 1):

You can add any chars to a Java `String`. But a `String` is probably not what you want if you just want to transmit binary data. Consider using a `byte[]` or some other byte-oriented interface.