# how to send a .text file containing ESC/POS commands to a printer from java code

Tags: java, printing

What i have so far is the following code:

```
 FileInputStream fin =new FileInputStream(filename);
 DocFlavor df = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;                    
 Doc d = new SimpleDoc(fin, df, null);   
 PrintService P = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();

  if (P != null) {              
     DocPrintJob job = P.createPrintJob();  
     job.print(d, null);  
            }
    fin.close;
```

the code is working fine but the printer does't interpret the commands if the file containing commands, it keep printing the exact string content of the file.
so how to send command to Epson receipt printer ?

Comment: Are you sending the actual escape character preceding the command?  In other words, are there ASCII characters with the value 27 (0x1B) in the text file?  These can sometimes be a bit of a pain to find a way to insert, but for example, Notepad++ will easily allow it by using Edit->Character Panel.

Comment: do you mean this to be the first line int the txt file:
PRINT #1, CHR$(&H1B);"@";

if so yes.

Comment: It's evident that you know more about communicating with a printer than I do, but no, I meant actually putting a single escape character in your text file.  This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164703/adding-non-printable-chars-to-a-string-in-java) is in line with what I mean.  However, if you want all of your data for the printer to come from the text file, those characters will have to be embedded in the text file.

Comment: well, i dont know actually, thank you. it is unnecessary for all the data to come from txt file, however will try to append the stream coming from the file with escape char and will let you know about the result, but what i meant that first command in the file i want to send is CHR$(&H1B) which refer to the same character.

Comment: HI David, i did try some commands from saved string then insert the char 27 in the first and append 3 in the end. The output came the same  but starts by 27 and end by 3. i still don't know how to do it

Comment: So you're seeing "27" and "3" in the printed output?  That seems unexpected; are you sure you inserted the characters into the output stream correctly?  In any case, I'm not sure about the suggestion; it just seemed that it was somewhat likely and the easiest thing to try.  If you expand the code in your question a bit and explicitly show an example of what the printed output looks like, you'll be more likely to get help from someone more knowledgeable. :)

Comment: maybe i am doing it wrong, how do you suggest please to append the esc char into the string. 

the modification is, by saving commands into a string 
and then get that string buffer, 
then inserted the char into the StringBuffer into index 0. 
therefore to get the inputstream of that string buffer. 
what do you suggest please to insert the char because i feel this is not the correct way to do it.
regards.

Comment: Probably first, see if that is something you need to do. What you described sounds right to me, but you can test it by replacing the escape character with something visible (e.g., 0x21 = '!') and seeing if you get that on your printed output (or in the final output before printing in the debugger, if you don't want to keep printing while trying things).

Comment: HI David you was absolutely right its fine now i, its working now.

Comment: Tahnk you, i have learned a lot from your simple remark.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As have been figured out that commands may have to be send directly not in ESC/POS format but you need to interpret the code to hexadecimal in you java code and send to printer as the way i post, whether from a file or string. 
as example instead of initializing the Epson receipt printer by:

```
  PRINT #1, CHR$(&H1B);"@";
```

and to cut the paper in receipt printer the code may be:

```
  PRINT #1, CHR$(&H1D);"V";CHR$(1);
```

so this is how it works for me.

```
    char[] initEP = new char[]{0x1b, '@'};
    char[] cutP = new char[]{0x1d,'V',1};
    String Ptxt=  new String(initEP)+ " text data \n \n \n"+ new String(cutP);
```

instead of

```
    Doc d = new SimpleDoc(new FileInputStream(filename), df, null);
```

use

```
    InputStream pis = new ByteArrayInputStream(Ptxt.getBytes());
    Doc d = new SimpleDoc(pis, df, null);
```

however it maybe a way to send code as its command format but desperately could't do that so far. and not sure if it can done from java.

Answer (score 1):

The last step is inserting the printer commands using their true ASCII values in your input file--e.g., the escape character is ASCII value 0x1B.  This can be done either by using an editor that allows inserting any ASCII value, such as a hex editor or Notepad++'s Character Panel (under the Edit menu), or by programmatically modifying the data sent to the printer after it is read from the file.

Comment: trying to get use of hex editor very useful in communication stuff

Answer (score 1):

When running linux (Ubuntu 12), this problem happens when the printer driver is 
generic + text. 
Selecting generic + raw queue, makes the printer behave more like a ESC POS device.