# How to append a string with ASCII end of text?

Tags: java, string, ascii

Basically I've two strings Says: `String a = "How are you"`, `String b = "john"`.

Now I need to transfer these 2 Strings to a client with a character that the client could understand that `a and b` contains 2 different values. I can't use any keyboard available characters in order to split them in client side. Based on looking on ASCII Table I found the most suitable character would be `ETX (End Of Text)`.

Example for to separate a line you would use:

`String a="How are you"+System.lineSeparator()+"john"`

(FYI: Can't use lineSeparator) My Need:

`String a="How are you"+ETX+"john"`

So I would really appreciate if some one tell me how to add ETX to a string and then use `split` to split the string.

Regards

Comment: If you can choose the character, it seems you control enough of the protocol and could also choose a more flexible/common wire format. For example `["How are you", "john"]` (JSON)

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1164855/335858) to the duplicate question may be of particular interest.